# Including AdMob and Omniture in an Android App

Tags: android, admob, adobe-analytics

I have been using **Omniture**  in my app.In the new version I am implementing **AdMob** tracking.
I do not add any reference in `Manifest` file for **omniture**. However for **AdMob** we need to specify a `INSTALL_REFERRER`. In AdMob tracking guide it is specified that when 2 analytics packages are used we need to separately list broadcast receivers. Otherwise it may block either of the 2. They have specified about Google Analytic. I am not sure if I need to handle this for omniture too. If yes, will it be the same way?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented this in my APP and it is in market already. I did not encounter any problem so far, hence I believe having Omniture  and AdMob tracking together does not cause any issues and both work properly.